# Peer.js on-event and angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webrtc

I am new to AngularJS as well as to Peer.js too. I am working on a small webrtc-application as a weekend project. To be able to do anything at all I would have to build a connection, which I do with this function or rather binding:

```
peer.on('open', function(id) {
    console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
    console.log("127.0.0.1/webRTC" + document.location.pathname + addUrlParam(document.location.search, "id", id));
});
```

Right now I am sending the url I am creating to the console, but I would of course rather display it somewhere useful. My question now is, how I would do that with AngularJS. I am coming from jQuery and could do something like:

```
$("#myElement").html(id);
```

But since I want to learn AngularJS I was wondering how I would do it?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is jQuery-driven for dom manipulations as it embeds at least jQuery lite

From Angular Doc

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

If you loaded jQuery (As you, stiller_leser, stated in your comment), you will be able to use

```
angular.element("#myElement").html(id);
```

[Here is the doc for Angular element methods](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

If not, for jqLite, use

```
angular.element( document.querySelector( '#some-id' ) );
```

Comment: Hey, it put me on the right track. It works like so `angular.element(document.getElementById("header")).html(id)` . Angular tells me that it doesn't support lookup by selector.